# Cannot convert type 'TestLinq.UserData' to T'estLinq.userData'

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Still working out concepts in EF6 (learning)  This is not production code; it's only for learning...

I'm experimenting with migrating to EF6 from direct SQL ODBC calls and trying to duplicate features of methods I have currently in my code.

Consider this code:

```
public class user
{
    [Key]
    public int pkID;
    public string ForeignID;
    public string UserName;
    public virtual List<userData> UserDatas { get; set; }
}

public class userData
{
    [Key]
    public int pkID;
    public int fkUserID;
    public string ColumnName;
    public string ColumnValue;
    public bool IsOverrode;
    public string OverrideValue;
}

class Program
{
    static TestDataEntities db = new TestDataEntities();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var record = db.Users.Select(x => new { x.UserName, x.pkID }).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(record);

        var record2 = db.Users.Include(x => x.UserDatas).FirstOrDefault();

        record2.UserName = "JohnTestNew";

        db.SaveChanges();

        var ud = record2.UserDatas.Where(x => x.ColumnName.ToUpper().Contains("FIRSTNAME")).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var item in record2.UserDatas)                
            Console.WriteLine(item.ColumnName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static userData TestReturn()
    {
        var record2 = db.Users.Include(x => x.UserDatas).FirstOrDefault();
        var ud = record2.UserDatas.Where(x => x.ColumnName.ToUpper().Contains("FIRSTNAME")).FirstOrDefault();
        return (userData)ud;
    }
```

I'm getting a compile error on the last line: 
return (userData)ud;
'Cannot convert type 'TestLinq.UserData' to 'TestLinq.userData'

I kind of understand what is going on, but I thought I could cast the class on the return.  The UserData is contained in the returned query, the userData is the raw class of what UserData is.

Is there a way to return this object using the base class?

Comment: What is `TestData`? It looks like it's a context that is using different classes than the ones you have defined here.

Comment: That is the EF6 data model to MSSQL

Comment: Yes, but the EF6 models are not the same classes that you have added here. Just because you have a class called `userData` doesn't mean it's the same thing as `UserData` defined elsewhere.

Comment: UserData would be the table name in MSSQL

Comment: Yes, but EF6 (I assume you have an EDMX file?) has already created a class called `UserData`

Comment: Yes, that is the "TestData", I edited the above code to give a little more info on what it is to "TestDataEntities" which would be the "default name" if I let it create it that way.

Comment: Please read what I wrote, and the error message, note that it say it cannot convert `TestLinq.UserData` to `TestLinq.userData`. Especially look at the capital `U`.

Comment: Yes, that works.  But can I cast it to a class that I've created which matches or must I use the EF class?

Comment: You can't randomly cast things to other types.

Comment: Ug.  Ok, I thought I was using the top classes in my queries; I am actually not. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, like I said in my first comment!

Comment: Thanks, I was doing extra work when I didn't have to.  Different concepts; trying to learn. Thanks again.